# Radial Distribution Function - Structure Factor relation, deriviation help

Tags: fourier-transform, diffraction

I'm attempting to prove the relation between the structure factor and the RDF, following the deriviation [here](http://www-thphys.physics.ox.ac.uk/people/ArdLouis/teaching/M10Mich05.pdf) (pg 92-94). The solution this source comes too disagrees with this [paper](http://journals.iucr.org/j/issues/2001/02/00/th0051/) which I trust more. I'm trying to prove this:

\begin{equation}
\rho[g(r)-1] = \frac{1}{2{\pi}^2 r}\int_{0}^{k_{max}}[A(k)-1]k sin(kr) dk
\nonumber
\end{equation}

Please try and help edit my method so far rather than posting your own deriviation.

---

*My attempt:*

The radial distribution function (RDF) of a structure is given by the bellow formula as explained [here](http://www-thphys.physics.ox.ac.uk/people/ArdLouis/teaching/M10Mich05.pdf) (pg 92-94).

\begin{equation}
g(\vec{r})  = g(r) = \frac{1}{N\rho}\langle{\sum_{i\neq{j}}^N{\delta(\vec{r}_{ij}-\vec{r})}}\rangle
\nonumber
\end{equation}
Where $\langle \rangle$ denotes time or ensemble average.

The structure factor is given by:
\begin{equation}
A(\vec{k}) = \frac{1}{N}\langle{\sum_{l,m}^N{exp[i\vec{k}\cdot(\vec{r}_l-\vec{r}_m)]}}\rangle
\nonumber
\end{equation}
Where $\langle \rangle$ denotes time or ensemble average.

\begin{equation}
A(\vec{k}) = \frac{1}{N}\langle{\sum_{l}^N{exp[i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{0}]}}\rangle+\frac{1}{N}\langle{\sum_{l\neq{m}}^N{exp[i\vec{k}\cdot(\vec{r}_l-\vec{r}_m)]}}\rangle=1+\frac{1}{N}\langle{\sum_{l\neq{m}}^N{exp[i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}_{lm}]}}\rangle
\nonumber
\end{equation}

Evaluating the Fourier transform in 3D, noting $g(\vec{r})=g(-\vec{r})$ and $\delta(\vec{r}) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}\int e^{i\vec{k} \cdot \vec{r}}d^3\vec{k}$:
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{3/2}}\int{A(\vec{k})e^{i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}}d^3\vec{k}} = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{3/2}}\int{e^{i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}}d^3\vec{k}}
+ \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{3/2}}\int{\frac{1}{N}\langle{\sum_{l\neq{m}}^N{e^{i\vec{k}\cdot(\vec{r}_{lm}+\vec{r})}}}\rangle d^3\vec{k}}
\nonumber
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}\int{A(\vec{k})e^{i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}}d^3\vec{k}} = \delta(\vec{r})
+ \frac{1}{N}\langle{\sum_{l\neq{m}}^N{\delta(\vec{r}_{lm}+\vec{r})}}\rangle
\nonumber
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}\int{A(\vec{k})e^{i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}}d^3\vec{k}} = \delta(\vec{r}) + \rho g(-\vec{r})
\nonumber
\end{equation}

*Where I'm stuck/confused:*
The first [source](http://www-thphys.physics.ox.ac.uk/people/ArdLouis/teaching/M10Mich05.pdf) keeps the delta function but I need a -1 on both sides to reach the final result not just one.

My idea:
$\delta(\vec{r}) = 0$ if $\vec{r} \neq 0  \therefore$ ignore as only interested in $r > 0$???

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}\int{A(\vec{k})e^{i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}}d^3\vec{k}} =  \rho g(\vec{r})
\nonumber
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
g(\vec{r}) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^3\rho}\int{A(\vec{k})e^{i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}}d^3\vec{k}} 
\nonumber
\end{equation}

For isotropic systems $A(\vec{k})=A(k)$ and $g(\vec{r}) = g(r)$ therefore in spherical polar coordinates ($d^3 \vec{k} = k^2sin\theta dk d\theta d\phi$ and $\vec{k}\cdot \vec{r} = krcos\theta$) :

\begin{equation}
g(r) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^3\rho}\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\pi} \int_{0}^{\infty}{A(k)e^{ikrcos\theta}k^2sin\theta dk d\theta d\phi} 
\nonumber
\end{equation}

Thus noting, $dcos\theta = -sin\theta d\theta$

\begin{equation}
g(r) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^3\rho}\int_{0}^{\infty}2\pi A(k)k^2 \int_{-1}^1 e^{ikrcos\theta}dcos\theta dk = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^3\rho}\int_{0}^{\infty}2\pi A(k)k^2 \left[ \frac{e^{ikrcos\theta}}{ikr}\right]_{-1}^{1}dk
\nonumber
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
g(r) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^3\rho}\int_{0}^{\infty}4\pi k^2A(k) \frac{sin(kr)}{kr} dk \approx
\frac{1}{2\pi^2\rho}\int_{0}^{k_{max}} A(k) \frac{sin(kr)}{kr}k^2 dk
\nonumber
\end{equation}

Some stuff I found in *[Underneath the Bragg Peaks](https://lns.pnpi.spb.ru/download/cryst/EgamiBillinge_StructuralAnalysis.pdf)* pg 92:

$S(k)$ approaches unity at high $k$ so that the integration oscillates widely as a function of k. To avoid this problem it is customary to subtract unity from $S(k)$. In this procedure what is really being done is to subtract the contribution from the average continuum, which corresponds to subtracting unity from $S(k)$ and $g(r)$, since when the density is uniform there is no difrraction and the structure factor is unity. Thus we obtain the standard expressions:

\begin{equation}
\rho[g(r)-1] = \frac{1}{2{\pi}^2 r}\int_{0}^{k_{max}}[A(k)-1]k sin(kr) dk
\nonumber
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
G(r) = \frac{1}{2\pi^2 \rho r}\int_{0}^{k_{max}}F(k)k sin(kr) dk
\nonumber
\end{equation}